# How do I obtain a smooth, white floor?

Tags: flooring

I'd like to obtain a smooth, seamless, a bit shiny, white floor in an apartment. Something similar to this:

[image: Smooth white floor example]

How can I achieve this? I was thinking about epoxy flooring. Is that the correct route to take in an apartment, or is there something else I should consider?

I would like to avoid applied sheets such as linoleum if possible.

Comment: "Apartment" often implies a rental. If you have a rental it seems that you'd have to anticipate a serious talk with the landlord before putting down a new floor.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, it's not a rental.

Comment: That floor looks nice...until the first time someone walks on it with bare feet or it's been >1 hour since you last swept... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot will depend upon the type of surface that the new flooring will be placed over. Epoxy floor covering may be best if over concrete sub floor. For other types of subfloors sheet vinyl may go a long way toward providing the look you want.

Proper preparation of the subfloor will be essential to getting a great look.

Here are some sheet vinyl ideas:

http://www.spec-net.com.au/press/0506/pla_030506.htm

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late to answer but whoever comes across this from now on can have an answer. To create this look over a concrete slab, it first needs to be diamond grinded, all cracks and divots need to be properly patched, then a good penetrating epoxy primer or waterproof membrane if vapor problems are present needs to be used. Next, to get that glass smooth look, the white epoxy needs to be poured, using a gauged or notched squeegee, then smoothed with proper tools. Finally, a polyurethane or multiple coats of finish is applied depending on the space that it will be used in. For example, the top coat requirements would be much different in a residence compared to a hotel lobby or retail space where high traffic is expected.

If this floor started out as plywood, we usually ask for 2 sheets of 3/4 inch exterior grade tongue and groove plywood, screwed and glued to be applied first. We then flash patch all the seams, apply a bonding primer and pour a polymer modified self leveling concrete with an anti fracture membrane. Now that we have a new canvas, we apply the epoxy system in the same manner as stated before.

Comment: If you are affiliated in any way with the product that you linked to, you **must** disclose that. Please see the [expected behavior](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), [product support](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/product-support) and [promotion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) pages in the [help] for more information. In the meantime, I've removed it since it doesn't add to the answer. You're welcome to include links in the "about me" section of your user profile.